# Placing Admin Post Metaboxes in Tabs

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, metabox, customization

I am looking for what code one would need to add into the functions.php file which would allow specific metaboxes to show up in tags instead of within their individual metaboxes. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Could you add [a mockup](http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups) of what you want to achieve? Your title says "Tabs", but your content says "tags". I assume "tags" is the typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can inspect http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/editor-tabs/

Comment: thanks - I appreciate the proposed answer but although this is essentially what I need I specifically require a way to define the order of the tabs for EACH custom post type. The other thing is that I wanted the post editor to be displayed within one the main default tab when the page loads and show a few metaboxes within that tab whereas other metaboxes I need to move over to different tabs. Any help in customizing this would be greatly appreciated.